# Check, using a list, if a string contains a certain letter or number

Tags: python

The question I'm answering requires you to validate a Car Reg Plate. It must look for a sequence of two letters, then three numbers, then three letters, otherwise return a message like "not a valid postcode"

I need to know how to check if a string contains a certain letter, or number, by comparing it with a list.

So far, I've got this:

```
# Task 2

import random
import re

def regNumber():
    # Generate a Car Reg Number
    letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

    letter1 = random.choice(letters)
    letter2 = random.choice(letters)
    number1 = random.choice(numbers)
    number2 = random.choice(numbers)
    letter3 = random.choice(letters)
    letter4 = random.choice(letters)
    letter5 = random.choice(letters)
    licensePlate = (letter1 + letter2 + number1 + number2 + letter3 + letter4 + letter5)
    return licensePlate, letters, numbers

carReg, letters, numbers = regNumber()

print(carReg)
if letters not in carReg: print("Success")
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to check `carReg` to see if it is not entirely letters. You constructed it from letters and numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be checking for *characters* in your string with this method, it will not simply iterate over your list for you. 
Try using something like this instead, to check every character in your list of strings:

```
if any(letter in carReg for letter in letters):
```

This will cut out on the first `True`, which is I think what you're looking for.

***Note:*** If using `any` like this is unfamiliar territory for you, you can also always just iterate over every string within your list of strings to check for those given characters.

***Update:*** If you're attempting to match a given format of letters and numbers, it would make much more sense (IMHO) for you to familiarize yourself with Python's  [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)  methods to pattern match to a valid license plate than attempt to use loops to validate one. I won't write the regex for your particular case, but to give you an idea, the following would allow you to match 3 letters followed by 1-4 digits (valid license plate where *I* live)

```
match_plate = re.compile(r"^[A-Z]{3}\d{1,4}$",re.I)
```

If you really must use a list to check, you will have to use a series of conditional statements to split the license plate into parts over which you can validate with iterations.

Comment: This or a set intersection, yeah.

Comment: This seems to work, but the question I'm answering requires you to validate a Car Reg Plate. It must look for a sequence of two letters, then three numbers, then three letters, otherwise return a message like "not a valid postcode".

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the exact issue in this case,

`letters` is a list being returend from `regNumber` but `in` requires a string on the leftside

like `'ASD111' in carReg`

Comment: So there's no way of using the list? It has to be individual strings?

Comment: @String you could check to see if a list contains another list , but not if a string contains a list

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if letters not in carReg: print("Success")
```

to

```
for l in letters:
    if l not in carReg: 
        print("Success")
```

in your code you are having a list of strings and, that is why I have changed your if condition to a for loop so that each element of the list is checked for occurance in carReg string.

alternatively, i think you should be using a flag to solve your probem. Like so:

```
flag = 0
for l in letters:
    if l in carReg: 
        flag = 1
        break

if flag == 0:
    print("Success")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without regular expressions:

Define the pattern you want using `str` methods in a list

```
pattern = [str.isalpha, str.isalpha,
           str.isdigit,  str.isdigit,  str.isdigit,
           str.isalpha, str.isalpha, str.isalpha]
```

Use that pattern to check a string.

```
def is_foo(pattern, s):
    '''Return True if s matches pattern

    s is a string
    pattern is a list of functions that return a boolean
    len(s) == len(pattern)
    each function in pattern is applied to the corresponding character in s
    '''
    # assert len(s) == len(pattern)
    return all(f(c) for f, c in zip(pattern, s))
```

Usage

```
if is_foo(pattern, 'aa111aaa'):
    print 'yes!!!'

if not is_foo(pattern, '11aa111'):
       print ':('
```

Comment: This seems like it would work. I'll give it a go tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way in which you could generate a certain number of letters rather than having to use so many variables would be to use just two variables that would allow the generation of, for the first one, 2 letters and for the second 3 letters.
An example of how I would implement this would be:

```
def randomLetters1(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in range(y))
firstLetters = (randomLetters1(2))
secondLetters = (randomLetters1(3))
```

I know this because I have had to do this exact same task.